# Page throws ViewState error when Items collection of dropdownlist is modified in IndexChanged event

Tags: asp.net, controls, state

I have an ASCX control which is a special dropdownlist. I add that control dynamically to the page and fill it with data. This control has a postback that will change the contents of a second dynamically created standard dropdownlist.

When I change the selection on the first dropdown, the indexchanged fires and I get new data and attempt to place it in the second dropdownlist's items collection, by first clearing it then filling it with new data.

This works fine the first time a change the selection, but when I select a second time the following error is thrown:

*The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.*

I'm not adding or removing new controls in the fired event, only changing data. And again, it works the first time, but doesn't subsequent times.

If I disable stateview on the child control, then the control just doesn't get updated with data at all.

Hope this is clear enough :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your ASCX - are you re-creating both Dropdown lists *each* time in the control's OnInit event? If they are created dynamically, they need to be created each time there is a postback and this must be done *before* ViewState's values are deserialized in to the control tree.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But actually I think this part of my code is actually working, yes I do create the controls OnInit, so that wasn't the issue. Turns out I am actually creating a different control structure very subtly.

Comment: Controls tree must be identical, otherwise .NET doesn't know where deserialized values should go. As an alternative, you can disable ViewState for that control / dynamic controls to make sure they aren't breaking your viewstate when page's control tree changes.